# I will take your life, to be honest

Tags: riddle

> At time, you see, the chime.
>
> When your brave, you see the time.
>
> Once, you see the difference.
>
> Then, you know its time
>
> I live in the sea.
>
> I hunt on the land.
>
> I kill those, who have no chance.
>
> While you hate me, you love me.
>
> In time, I sweep with my broom.
>
> My broom takes all. None can oppose,
>
> for those who do, are sweeped to hell.
>
> You have no chance to do it, so you know it.
>
> You jump when you see me, you run when you know.
>
> Hide with the eyes, those who know.
>
> I am everywhere, yet no where.
>
> I stalk you, but I dont.
>
> I lie through my teeth, yet I am honest.
>
> I will take your life, to be honest.

**WHO AM I?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This brings me to death/our life time

I'll try to explain the best i can

> At time, you see, the chime.
>
> When your brave, you see the time.
>
> Once, you see the difference.
>
> Then, you know its time
>
> > Chime brings me to "an agreement" or "the carillon(that was our life)" witch is when we face death and we know it is time. And when it is time, some people say you have "flashes" of your entire life just before die (you see the time).
>
> I live in the sea.
>
> I hunt on the land.
>
> I kill those, who have no chance.
>
> While you hate me, you love me.
>
> > What i get from this is that when you are suffering so much, when you are really close to death, you want to die, so you love death and you hate, at the same time.
>
> In time, I sweep with my broom.
>
> My broom takes all. None can oppose,
>
> for those who do, are sweeped to hell.
>
> You have no chance to do it, so you know it.
>
> > We cant escape because time is everything, that's what gives us everything and what takes away everything (time gives purpose to our existence).
>
> You jump when you see me, you run when you know.
>
> Hide with the eyes, those who know.
>
> > we still fear death though we can not escape, so, we try to "run" and "jump".
>
> I am everywhere, yet no where.
>
> I stalk you, but I dont.
>
> I lie through my teeth, yet I am honest.
>
> I will take your life, to be honest.
>
> > "i lie" and "i am honest" because we always imagine for us a good life, full of love and we don't think about bad things and that is the lie. What is "honest" is that life is unfair and there are good things and bad things in life because that's how our nature works (we are only humans), and sometimes we forget

Hope this makes sense for you. And if it doesn't just comment!

Comment: Hello and welcome to PSE. Please hide your answers in spoilers.

Comment: Ok, got it, sorry !

Answer (score 1):

Partial hmm, I wonder if this is something:

> When your brave, you see the time.

> brave -> courage. See-the-time c-our-age